# On click for Label with an embedded button

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

What's the correct way to handle a click on the Label without triggering the button?

Given the following html:

```
<label>
Label
<button> Remove</button>
</label>
```

Both css as javascript solutions are fine.

Comment: try getting the element using javascript then then listen to the onclick property

Comment: @net-js This works partially. It triggers the label click, but it also triggers the embedded button for some reason.

Comment: Add a second label inside it

Comment: If clicking the label should not trigger the button, the button should not be inside the label to begin with. I usually check the `nodeName` of `event.target` to see which element was clicked.

Comment: @Shilly for layout purposes it's interesting to have it inside the label. Since the label should be able to be both selected and removed. Could you provide me an example for event.target or nodeName? I'm not familiar with it. :/

Comment: @net-js Adding a second label seems to work for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `e.stopPropagation();` on child.

```js
  let label = document.querySelector("label");
  let button = document.getElementById("remove-button");
  label.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("Label Clicked!");
  });
  button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

```html
<label>
  Label
  <button id="remove-button">Remove</button>
</label>
```

Comment: If this solution helps you out. Please do accept the answer. Thanks!